# Vyper Local compiler failed to fetch

Tags: vyper

I have vyper installed and my local compiler and remix both on http://localhost:8000
However, when i go to compile it, i get the error in remix saying failed to fetch. and in my mac terminal i get:

Listening on http://localhost:8000

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2022 11:07:55] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2022 11:07:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I am able to compile contracts using my terminal, but i need to be able to deploy/test them via remix. Any help would be very appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is late but i'll leave this for anyone else who's currently going through this issue on Remix. You're most likely going through the common compiler error.
The fix is quite simple and not even technical. Just switch from local compiler to remote compiler with a simple click on the left side.

[image: from remix]